# magento 1 domain name change causes COrS errors and site breaks

Tags: domain, cors

I have two magento 1 sites on separate servers - this is doubltless the wrong way to have gone about doing this and i'm still on a (steep) learning curve with changin themes in M1

https://www.petrolthreads.co.uk  (old site) (M1 1.9.2.1 php5.6)

https://www.petrolmugs.com (development/new site M1 192.4.2  php7.2)

they both work just fine - old site is slow and, well, old and the new site is ready to replace the old site so this is what I've done:-

1. changed the domain for the whm/cpanel account for petrolmugs to petrolthreads.co.uk
2. edited the base-urls in the cor_config_data table to be http://www.petrolthreads.co.uk/ and https://www.petrolthreads.co.uk/ for unsecure and secure respectively.
3. pointed the petrolthreads.co.uk dns to the new server.

i can browse to the new site via petrolthreads.co.uk but the site doesn't work - it has lots of CORS errors (for fonts) and 404 not found (for the slider) and the currency switch stops working.

I have no idea where to look and any suggestions/help would be appreciated. images show the problems - i've undone my doings and sites are back to working now.

[image: CORS and 404 errors]

[image: slider not loading]

Answer (score 0):

Well as you see in the console errors you still have petrolmugs links in your code or database.

I would suggest the following :

1. Make a coffee
2. Backup new site db
3. Find and replace `petrolmugs.co.uk` for `petrolthreads.co.uk`
4. Drop and reimport the database to a new db
5. do the same for your code if there are hardcoded links
6. Test your new database by changing your credentials to `app/etc/local.xml` pointing to the new database.

Hope these help. Reply me if you need further assistance.

Have a nice day.

Comment: thanks - that's kind of where I'm at, but a little longer winded. I'm going to do the standard "move to a new host" M1 process - dump the DB, create a new cpanel account for petrolthreads.co.uk, create new DB, restore the DB from petrolmugs and edit the local.xml.

As ever, simple shortcuts never seem to be either simple or short.... heigh ho.

Comment: so I did the following:- 

---dumped the DB

---created a new whm/cpanel account

---copied all the files to the new account

---gave the files /directories the correct ownership and permissions

---added the @sets@ to the beginning and end of the DB

---imported the DB in to te new WHM/cpanel user

---searched the entire DB for "petrolmugs" and replaced with "petrolthreads" (only a few entries in core_config)

---cleared all the caches

---reindexed all

>>>and its exactly the same :( :( :(

Comment: I've left both sites running for now in case anyone can see something really obvious that I've missed....

Comment: ok, so wierdly its working now. perhaps there was some residual caching somewhere (i use cloudflare, but that was only providing dns, no caching and I cleared all the magento caches and all my browser caches.

Only thing left now is that on mobile the currency switcher is not working - it works on https://www.petrolmugs.com , but not on https://www.petrolthreads.co.uk